# Two commands in one batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have those lines of codes, they are working just fine, however I want to unite them in same batch file, and execute sequentially, without making separate batch files, as if for example I want Code 1 to be executed first, and then Code 2, but I don't know what commands to use and how? Thank you.

Code 1.

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m  *.* /D -0 /C "cmd /c echo "Y" | del @path"
```

Code 2.

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s /D -0 /C "cmd /c echo "Y" | rd @path"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, just place them on different lines.

Batchfiles basically run each line as if they were entered in a command prompt.

Your batchfile would look like this:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m  *.* /D -0 /C "cmd /c echo "Y" | del @path"
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s /D -0 /C "cmd /c echo "Y" | rd @path"
```

Comment: Oh, just like that? And it would know the sequence which to execute first and which second?

Comment: it executes them sequentially

Comment: @Damo Batch files are executed from top to bottom (unless they contain a `goto` to an earlier label in the file).

Comment: Doesn't this first execute the first command on all the matching files, then the second one on all of them? That's not necessarily the same as executing the pair, one after the other, for each matching file.

Comment: @martineau yes it is, but that was not what the OP asked. They simply wanted to know how 2 batchfiles can be merged in 1 batch file. Knowing this makes it possible to extend the batchfile with other commands as well.